# PHP sum specific key sorted by 2 others

Tags: php, arrays

I want to sum only 1 key, but sorted by the other 2:

```
<?php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [week] => 1
            [info] => a
            [hours] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [week] => 2
            [info] => a
            [hours] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [week] => 2
            [info] => a
            [hours] => 4
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [week] => 2
            [info] => b
            [hours] => 4
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [week] => 2
            [info] => c
            [hours] => 4
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [week] => 3
            [info] => b
            [hours] => 4
        )
    [6] => Array
        (
            [week] => 3
            [info] => b
            [hours] => 4
        )
)
?>
```

I want to sum the hours sorted by week. Every week has infos.
So first i want to sum the hours for every info and then sort them by week.

example:

```
week:1  info:a   hours:4
week:2  info:a   hours:8
week:2  info:b   hours:4
week:2  info:c   hours:4
week:3  info:b   hours:8
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to rearrange the array:

```
$todisplay = array();
foreach ($weeks as $week) {
   //Does not properly check for set keys; you should do isset checks
   $todisplay[$week['week']][$week['info']] += $week['hours'];
}
ksort($todisplay);
```

Then you can iterate over `todisplay` to build the table.

Comment: i forgot to mention, that info is an character

Comment: @galileoGalilei that will make absolutely no difference.

Comment: but it doesnt work, now i get a notice in php:undefined index a

Comment: @galileoGalilei you should be able to ignore the notices but didn't you see my comment? `//Does not properly check for set keys; you should do isset checks`